# How to calculate Monthly Sum of multiple table in single loop, using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table Table A and Table B in mysql Database

Table A

```
id     date     advanced         payed_remaining        remaining_date
1    1/1/2018     400                 800                   4/1/2018
2    2/1/2018     600                 600                   3/1/2018
3    4/1/2018     800                 200                   6/1/2018
4    6/1/2018     400                 300                   8/1/2018
5    3/2/2018     600                 200                   6/2/2018
6    8/2/2018     800                 400                   10/2/2018
```

Table B

```
id     date      amount    
1    1/1/2018     900     
2    2/1/2018     600     
3    4/1/2018     300 
4    2/2/2018     400
5    5/2/2018     800
```

Query for fetching monthly Data from both table,

```
$monthly_res = $con->prepare("SELECT t2.month, t2.total_advance, t2.total_pay_remaining, t1.total_income_amount FROM (SELECT  month(B.date) as month, SUM(B.income_amount) as total_income_amount FROM B group by month(B.date)) t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT month(A.date) as month, month(A.due_date) as month, t1.total_income_amount, SUM(A.advance) as total_advance, SUM(A.pay_remaining) as total_pay_remaining, t1.total_income_amount FROM A) t2 ON t2.month  = t1.month");
    $monthly_res->execute();
    while ($row = $monthly_res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $month = $row['month'];
        $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
        $month_name = $dt->format('F');
        $total = $row['total_advance'] + $row['total_income_amount'] + $row['total_pay'];
        echo "<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>".$month_name."</td>
                <td>".$total."/-</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>";
    }
```

## 1054 - Unknown column 't1.total_income_amount' in 'field list'

when i remove t1.total_income_amount from query its showing December result only...

I want fetch monthly sum of advanced, sum of payed_remaining, sum of amount in one loop.

```
Result= sum(advanced) + sum(payed_remaining) + sum(amount) by month 

January : 5900

February : 3200
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with below query

```
SELECT month(A.date) as month, SUM(A.advanced) as total_advance, SUM(A.payed_remaining) as total_pay_remaining, month(B.date) as month, SUM(B.income_amount) as total_income_amount 
From A
join B on month(A.date) = month(B.date)
group by month(A.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should  join the aggregated  result eg:

```
      SELECT t2.month
      , t2.total_advance
      , t2.total_pay_remaining
      , t1.total_income_amount FROM (
            SELECT  month(B.date) as month
              , SUM(B.income_amount) as total_income_amount 
            FROM B group by month(B.date)
      ) t1 
      INNER JOIN (  
            SELECT month(A.date) as month
              , SUM(A.advance) as total_advance
              , SUM(A.pay_remaining) as total_pay_remaining
            FROM A
      ) t2 ON t2.month  = t1.month
```

You should explict join clause and AND operator and join the sum of the b table

Comment: SELECT t2.month, 
    t2.total_advance, 
    t2.total_pay_remaining, 
    t1.total_income_amount 
FROM (
SELECT  month(B.date) as month 
    SUM(B.income_amount) as total_income_amount  
FROM B 
group by month(B.date)) 
t1 INNER JOIN (
SELECT month(A.date) as month,
       month(A.remaining_date) as month,
         SUM(A.advanced) as total_advance, 
         SUM(A.pay_remaining) as total_pay_remaining, 
                  t1.total_income_amount 
FROM A) 
t2 ON t2.month  = t1.month

Comment: I try with above query but its showing syntax error

Comment: answer  update  ..  eventually show me the exact error message

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(B.income_amount) as total_income_amount  
FROM income 
group by mon' at line 7

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't1.total_income_amount' in 'field list'

Comment: check better and be sure you have the t1 after thye closing ) for FROM

Comment: i checked,  Everything is fine but still getting error.

Comment: seems there was some copy and paste issue  and tiotal_income was present also in wrong place ...asnwer  updated . with the (hope) correct code ..